# Grails, can't get an instance of the Role-class in spring-scurity-core

Tags: grails, spring-security

How can I get an instance of a specific role using the authority-string?
I've almost everything but I always get null in the result.
Like: Role.get('ROLE_ADMIN') returns null.

Have an action defined in the usercontroller that should add/remove roles for specified user. The code below contains a lot of testcode and everyhing looks work except that I can not retrieve an instance from the Role-class

```
def userroles() {
    def user = User.get(params.id)
    List<String> userRoles = roleNamesFromUser(user)
    List<String> uRoles = roleNamesFromParams()
    println(">> ROLES >>> params: "+uRoles)
    println(">> ROLES >>> userRoles: "+userRoles)

    for (uRole in uRoles) {
        println("#### Params: "+uRole)
        if (uRole in userRoles) {
            println("#### Role already used: "+uRole)

        } else { 
            println("#### userRole to be Created1: "+uRole)
            def role = Role.findByAuthority(uRole)
//                println("#### userRole to be Created2: "+role.authority)
//                UserRole.create user, role
            def ur = new UserRole(user:user, role: role).save(flush:true, failOnError:true)
            println("#### Role Created: "+ur.role.authority+" - username: "+ur.user.username)
        }
    }
    for (role in userRoles) {
        if (role in uRoles) {
            println("#### Role already exist: "+role)

        } else {
            Role.findByAuthority(uRole).delete()
            println("#### Role deleted: "+role)
        }
    }
    userRoles = roleNamesFromUser(user)
    for (role in userRoles) {
       println("#### After update - Role: "+role) 
    }


    UserRole.withSession {
        it.flush()
        it.clear()
    }

    redirect action:"index"
}
protected List<String> roleNamesFromParams() {
params.keySet().findAll { it.contains('ROLE_') && params[it] == 'on' } as List
}
protected List<String> roleNamesFromUser(User user) {
    def ur = user.getAuthorities().toList()
    def List<String> ul = new ArrayList<String>()
    def String auth
    for(int i=0; i<ur.size; i++){
        auth = ur[i].authority
        ul.add(auth)
    }
    return ul
}
```

The console shows this over a run:

```
>> ROLES >>> params: [ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_SALES, ROLE_SUPPLIER]
>> ROLES >>> userRoles: [ROLE_ADMIN]
%%%%% ROLE_ADMIN %%%%%#### Params: ROLE_ADMIN
#### Role already used: ROLE_ADMIN
#### Params: ROLE_SALES
#### userRole to be Created1: ROLE_SALES
2017-06-01 15:40:34.388 ERROR --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.g.web.errors.GrailsExceptionResolver   : ValidationException occurred when processing request: [POST] /user/userroles - parameters:
version: 0
id: 9
_ROLE_ADMIN: 
ROLE_ADMIN: on
_ROLE_USER: 
_ROLE_SALES: 
ROLE_SALES: on
_ROLE_SUPPLIER: 
ROLE_SUPPLIER: on
Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.torntrading.security.UserRole' on field 'role': rejected value [null]; codes [com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.error.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.error.role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.error.com.torntrading.security.Role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.error,userRole.role.nullable.error.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,userRole.role.nullable.error.role,userRole.role.nullable.error.com.torntrading.security.Role,userRole.role.nullable.error,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.com.torntrading.security.Role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable,userRole.role.nullable.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,userRole.role.nullable.role,userRole.role.nullable.com.torntrading.security.Role,userRole.role.nullable,nullable.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,nullable.role,nullable.com.torntrading.security.Role,nullable]; arguments [role,class com.torntrading.security.UserRole]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]
. Stacktrace follows:

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException: null
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass$ReflectionInvoker.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:210)
    at org.grails.core.DefaultGrailsControllerClass.invoke(DefaultGrailsControllerClass.java:187)
    at org.grails.web.mapping.mvc.UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.handle(UrlMappingsInfoHandlerAdapter.groovy:90)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:963)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:897)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:970)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:872)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:846)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.filter.ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ApplicationContextHeaderFilter.java:55)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:317)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:127)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:91)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:115)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(UpdateRequestContextHolderExceptionTranslationFilter.groovy:64)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.filter.GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(GrailsAnonymousAuthenticationFilter.groovy:53)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:158)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:169)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:200)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.authentication.logout.MutableLogoutFilter.doFilter(MutableLogoutFilter.groovy:62)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at grails.plugin.springsecurity.web.SecurityRequestHolderFilter.doFilter(SecurityRequestHolderFilter.groovy:58)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:331)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:214)
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:177)
    at org.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsWebRequestFilter.doFilterInternal(GrailsWebRequestFilter.java:77)
    at org.grails.web.filters.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:67)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: grails.validation.ValidationException: Validation Error(s) occurred during save():
- Field error in object 'com.torntrading.security.UserRole' on field 'role': rejected value [null]; codes [com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.error.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.error.role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.error.com.torntrading.security.Role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.error,userRole.role.nullable.error.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,userRole.role.nullable.error.role,userRole.role.nullable.error.com.torntrading.security.Role,userRole.role.nullable.error,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable.com.torntrading.security.Role,com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role.nullable,userRole.role.nullable.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,userRole.role.nullable.role,userRole.role.nullable.com.torntrading.security.Role,userRole.role.nullable,nullable.com.torntrading.security.UserRole.role,nullable.role,nullable.com.torntrading.security.Role,nullable]; arguments [role,class com.torntrading.security.UserRole]; default message [Property [{0}] of class [{1}] cannot be null]

    at org.grails.orm.hibernate.AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.save(AbstractHibernateGormInstanceApi.groovy:131)
    at org.grails.datastore.gorm.GormEntity$Trait$Helper.save(GormEntity.groovy:151)
    at com.torntrading.security.UserController$$EQLIup0W.$tt__userroles(UserController.groovy:46)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate$2.doInTransaction(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:133)
    at grails.transaction.GrailsTransactionTemplate.execute(GrailsTransactionTemplate.groovy:93)
    ... 37 common frames omitted
```

====================================

The database contains this:

```
id  version authority
1   0   ROLE_ADMIN
2   0   ROLE_USER
3   0   ROLE_SALES
4   0   ROLE_SUPPLIER
```

Comment: Are the database roles actually prefixed with ROLE_ ? I know when I create LDAP groups I don't prefix with ROLE_ but when checking roles for a user I have to add prefix so assume the plugin prefixes if not present.

Comment: Yes, it does. At the bottom of my question, there's a printout from the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this way: `Role.findByAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")` ?

Comment: Yes! That did it! I have tried that but there was a problem with the authority string. I didn't realize how hard it is to make use of this simple class. After some failing tests I finally discovered that what I thought would be a simple string containing just 'ROLE_ADMIN' I got something like '[UserRole authority: ROLE_ADMIN]'. And then I tested different solutions and forgot 'findByAuthority' just remembered that it didn't work. Ok, now it works, thanks a lot, this has been the most frustrating problem I ever had.